# Autoloading classes in pimcore

Tags: zend-framework, pimcore

I've created a fresh PHP-class, named it `Application_Form_Login` and saved it as `Application_Form_Login.php` inside the `/website/lib` directory. But everytime I'm running pimcore it refuses to load that file. What am I doing wrong here?

I've been looking at the [Zend autoloader](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html) and trying to find out the issue.

I've noticed that in pimcore bootstrapping all the relevant directories are added to the include path. But they don't seem to get checked. Or maybe my file isn't named correctly to be picked up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your filename should be /website/lib/Application/Form/Login.php

From the page you just quoted:

```
Each "_" character in the CLASS NAME is converted to a DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. The "_" character has no special meaning in the namespace.
```